# When enabling a systemd-service why it isn't started?

Tags: systemd, services

When running

```
systemctl enable my-service
```

it gets correctly enabled (the link is created into the right WantedBy-target in /etc/systemd/system) but it is not started.

However, when rebooting the machine systemd starts the service.

What do I need to do to have systemd start the service when enabling the service?

For reference, here's my unit-file:

```
[Unit]
Description=WebSocket-server-application

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ws-server.app
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(A little bit of background: `systemctl enable` is called during package-installation. I need to have the service started once the package has been installed.)

Comment: Try `systemctl enable --now myservice`

Comment: It answers my question. But unfortunately it does not solved my problem regarding preset-files. I will make another question.